# send a json file using ASP.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I was using this get method

```
public object Get()
{
    string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\data.json");

    object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

but I got this error

> NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is not supported.

I also tried this method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\data.json", FileMode.Open);

    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return result;
}
```

The error I got was

> CS1061:'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and no accessible extension method 'CreateResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix it? Also Is there any other way I can solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference the System.Web.dll for HttpResponseMessage Get() to work.

Add a reference to System.Web.dll. This assembly is also available in the
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\data.json", FileMode.Open);

    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't mind me asking but how do I do that. Some solutions I found online talks about finding reference in solution explorer however I am using visual studio and there is no reference in the solution explorer. If i just add "using System.Web.dll" it gives me error. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on References, then select Add References, then browse to System.Web.dll

[image]